# Setting CORS Headers on the apex of the API with multiple base path mappings?

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway

I have multiple base path mappings to stages:

- `/v1` - master
- `/latest` - staging
- `/glhf` - develop

I need to set a CORS OPTIONS response at the very root of my domain (api.naftuli.wtf in us-east-1) so that I can access my API over JavaScript. I have added an OPTIONS response for one of my resources, but targeting the root resource leads only to targeting `/v1`, `/latest`, or `/glhf`, and not the root of the domain.

Is there a way to set CORS headers on the apex of the API underneath the base path mappings? I cannot declare an empty base path mapping according to the API since I already have some, so I can't see a way to provide CORS suppport for my API, which is kind of a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noted, you can enable CORS for the root resource within an API and then access it via {api-id}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/ or {custom-domain-name}/base-path/

There is currently no way to enable CORS headers for the absolute root (path /) such as {api-id}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ or {custom-domain-name}/

The API Gateway team is actively working on a new feature which should allow customers to enable CORS for these cases.  Unfortunately, we cannot communicate any estimated delivery date.

Until that is available, the only way to enable CORS on an absolute root is to set-up a custom domain name with a base path mapping giving an empty base path and including the stage.  In that case, {custom-domain-name}/ will map to the root resource in your API on the stage your specified in the base path mapping.  This approach only supports using a single API/stage per custom domain name.  As a work-around, you could create a sub-domain for each of your APIs/stages and set-up a separate custom domain name for each subdomain like

- v1.api.naftuli.wtf
- latest.api.naftuli.wtf
- develop.api.naftuli.wtf

Comment: Thank you so much for answering these questions, this has been extremely helpful! Hope to see the new CORS feature soon, will reorient in meantime.